# dope sheet -- how to show two or more NLA strips (actions) belonging to one object

Tags: dopesheet, nla-editor

I have an animation set up in the NLA editor with two or more actions for many of the objects.  The dope sheet only seems to be able to show one action per object.   Example:  I have a flower object with gesture poses on one NLA strip and the flower's horizontal movement on another NLA strip.  I can get either of these actions to show under the flower object's name in the Dope Sheet, but not both at the same time.  I can switch from one to the other by going to the Action Editor and choosing an action.  Then it shows up in the dope sheet, but it seems you can't choose more than one action at a time, so only one shows up in the Dope Sheet.  Is there a work-around for this?  Thanks.
Zaffer